# New image name for iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios6

With the retina we make images with the @2x in the name. I see where the default image has to be default-568h@2x but this does not seem to be the case for other images. Like if my background is bg.png and bg@2x.png I tried using bg-568h@2x.png but that does not work. Can somebody tell me what the images need to be named to support the iPhone 5?

Comment: If you are looking for something similar to `~iPad` or `~iPhone` (like `~586h`) there isn't anything build in like that. But you can easily add it yourself by expanding UIImage class. Have a look at [this source snippet (UIImage+Retina4)](http://www.sourcedrop.net/FY53a14b0127f) for information about how to achieve. Just add this UIImage category and there will be support for ~568h@2x files.

Comment: As answered there is no suffix that automatically works. There is an alternative solution explained at http://angelolloqui.com/blog/20-iPhone5-568h-image-loading

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is no specific image name. Having the Default-568h@2x will launch that image on an iPhone 5 or iPod Touch 5G and will enable the non-letterbox mode. After that, you need to design your views to be flexible. There is no special "image name" or anything for the new size.

For your background, for example, you should probably be using an image that is capable of stretching or tiling and have it configured properly before setting it.

Answer (score 56):

No special suffix for iPhone 5 (4'' display), just the specific Default-568h@2x.png file.

Here's a macro to handle it:

```
// iPhone 5 support
#define ASSET_BY_SCREEN_HEIGHT(regular, longScreen) (([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height <= 480.0) ? regular : longScreen)
```

Usage: (assets names - image.png, image@2x.png, image-568h@2x.png)

```
myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:ASSET_BY_SCREEN_HEIGHT(@"image",@"image-568h")];
```

Comment: Great solution!! I would suggest just a little change in the macro in order to simplify coding: `#define ASSET_BY_SCREEN_HEIGHT(regular) (([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height <= 480.0) ? regular : [regular stringByAppendingString:@"-568h"])`

Comment: Very clean solution!
Apple should have made this available automatically with the imageNamed: API

Comment: @user1470914 Either would work, I've added it to 'macros.h' file and imported it in the .pch so macro is available from all files

Comment: No longer works consistently in iOS 8 because the UIScreen mainScreen bounds are rotated if the device is in landscape.  If your app doesn't rotate then it should be fine

Answer (score 1):

iPhone 5 does not have a different pixel density, it's the same retina display PPI as the iPhone 4/4S, it's just a different screen size. The @2x images will be used on iPhone 5 as well as 4/4S.

Comment: It is a different resolution.  Instead of 640x960 (which is iPhone 4/4S) it is 640x1136.

Comment: Yea what I meant is pixel density.

Comment: To stay consistent, Wasim, don't refer to the pixel quantities as the pixel density, it's not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

To complete Jason's answser, I would propose: What about overriding the `UIImage`'s `imageNamed:` method to have it happen the "-568" suffix to the name of your image? Or add a new method called `resolutionAdaptedImageNamed:` to the `UIImage` maybe using a category.

If I have a bit of time in the next days, I will try to post the code for that.

Caution: will not work for images in the Nib files.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Xcode 5, you can use asset catalog (see usage there [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013303-CH1-SW1))

Once your asset catalog is created `[ UIImage imagedNamed: @"your_image_set" ]` will pull right image based on device.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make category for this just make category as below .

```
UIImage+Retina4.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>
 @interface UIImage (Retina4)
 @end

UIImage+Retina4.m
#import "UIImage+Retina4.h"
static Method origImageNamedMethod = nil;
@implementation UIImage (Retina4)

+ (void)initialize {
origImageNamedMethod = class_getClassMethod(self, @selector(imageNamed:));
method_exchangeImplementations(origImageNamedMethod,
                               class_getClassMethod(self, @selector(retina4ImageNamed:)));
}
+ (UIImage *)retina4ImageNamed:(NSString *)imageName {
// NSLog(@"Loading image named => %@", imageName);
NSMutableString *imageNameMutable = [imageName mutableCopy];
NSRange retinaAtSymbol = [imageName rangeOfString:@"@"];
if (retinaAtSymbol.location != NSNotFound) {
    [imageNameMutable insertString:@"-568h" atIndex:retinaAtSymbol.location];
} else {
    CGFloat screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
    if ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.f && screenHeight == 568.0f) {
        NSRange dot = [imageName rangeOfString:@"."];
        if (dot.location != NSNotFound) {
            [imageNameMutable insertString:@"-568h@2x" atIndex:dot.location];
        } else {
            [imageNameMutable appendString:@"-568h@2x"];
        }
    }
}

NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imageNameMutable ofType:@"png"];
if (imagePath) {
    return [UIImage retina4ImageNamed:imageNameMutable];
} else {
    return [UIImage retina4ImageNamed:imageName];
}
return nil;
}

@end
```

And you can directly check using import this category as below where you wont to check 568 or normal image

```
imgvBackground.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"bkground_bg"];//image name without extantion
```