# How can I support the larger iPhone 5 screen with an older version of Xcode?

Tags: xcode, xcode3.2, iphone-5

I have developed an iOS app using **Xcode 3.2** and I would like to release a new version of the app that supports the larger iPhone 5 screen.

I have tried the following in the Application Delegate:

```
[window setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
[window addSubview:viewController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];

CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

NSLog(@"%@",[NSValue valueWithCGRect:screenBounds]);
// NSRect: {{0, 0}, {320, 480}}
```

As you can see the height is set to 480pt. How can I add support for the iPhone 5's taller screen?

Thanks,

Comment: Does Xcode 3.2 support iOS 6? iPhone 5 only runs iOS6, and requires Default-568h@2x.png to be added to the bundle. I think you need to upgrade your Xcode to a recent version.

Comment: By adding the extra launch image as @Jessedc suggest `UIScreen` might report back the correct height into your `result`.

Comment: Just I am trying . Thanks fro your reply

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have succeeded with your guidelines. But I am unable to up vote to your comments. I am sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the new standard `Default-568h@2x.png` image to your main bundle and run your app on an iPhone 5. If it doesn't appear at the full resolution you may need need to upgrade your version of Xcode and compile the app against a newer iOS SDK. Xcode 3.2 has been deprecated for some time now.

**Edit** It appears that simply adding the `Default-568h@2x` launch image on an earlier SDK works as the OP mentioned. This is pretty handy to know.

As a side note, there is another answer on the new [iPhone 5 launch image name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497776/new-image-name-for-iphone-5)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have succeeded with your guidelines. But I am unable to up vote to your comments. I am sorry