# Background with 3 resolution in UIImageView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, interface-builder

I have Background `UIImageView` in my `UIViewController`, and i set this backgound in `Interface builder` with a image that i have in three resolution:

```
1) bg.png
2) bg@2x.png
3) bg-568@2x.png
```

And i noticed that when i run my app on iPhone 5 the backgound is the bg.png and not the bg-568@2x. Any idea why it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated on this thread, suffix -568h only applies for Default image (splash screen).

[New image name for iPhone 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497776/new-image-name-for-iphone-5)

Comment: So what i should do for setting the bg to be the bigger one